# how to get data from bottom to top from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get data from bottom to top (from the last item uploaded to the first item uploaded like Instagram) but I couldn't make this. I searched a lot and found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395382/how-to-retrieve-data-from-bottom-to-top-from-firebase-database-in-recyclerview-o/42395745#42395745).

I made it with firebaseRecyclerAdapter and worked fine but with custom Adapter I couldn't do it!

**here is the method I used:**

```
@Override
    public ItemsRecyclerView getItem(int pos){
        return super.getItem(getCount() - 1 - pos);
    }
```

Comment: Did you also try the first solution given in that answer (which svi.data also answered below)? Since that solution only depends on Android's layout mechanism, it seems more fit for a case where you're not using FirebaseUI.

Comment: What does your DB structure look like and how are you querying/fetching the data?

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is reversing the recyclerview, forget about the method that you used above.

And do this when you set your recycler view:

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
manager.setReverseLayout(true);
manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recycler_View.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

**Possible solution:**

try this:

Maybe try to reverse the list that you pass to your adapter like this:

```
//your list
List<model> your_list = new ArrayList()<>;

//before you pass it to the adapter do this
Collections.reverse(your_list);

//now your list is reversed, pass it to the adapter
Adapter adapter = new Adapter (your_list,.....,....);
```

Comment: I'm using gridlayout !

Comment: @MohamedElFwakhry ahh then this solution won't work for you.

Comment: you have any solution !